# how to split a string and put it into an array in a listview that is in an alertbox

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I wanted to know how to split a string then put it into an array in a listview that is in an alertbox.

This is a 3 part question:
splitting the string and putting in an array
putting the array into a listview (or dropdown box)
putting the listview into an alertbox

thanks for the help

Comment: we are not here to programm for you, you should try to develop your app , and then when you have a problem you can post a question , 
for splitting a string , there is a method to split a string : string.split(string separator); it return an array of Strings , 
And for the listView , do some search in the website and you will find your happyness ( take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=listView+in+AlertDialog+in+Android )

Comment: It would be easier for someone to just write the code for you.  Are you sure you want to be a developer and not a manager.   If not, then at some point you're going to need to learn how to write programs.  (Java For Dummies is a popular book for beginners.(

Comment: Born able to program were you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
String date = "25.7.2011"
String []ar=date.split("[.]");
```